# Why does website hosted by Amazon S3 make me download all pages except index.html

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I converted a bucket containing data files to be a website

I added this page works okay, and view as a webpage in Firefox
http://artist.albunack.net.s3-website-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/index.html

But when I try to view existing pages such as

http://artist.albunack.net.s3-website-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/0ab688fd-0943-41cd-a24c-78ec2baad3fd.html

Firefox what me to download them as if they are not html pages, why would this be ?

Comment: Its possible the content type has been messed up some how, click on the file in the s3 console page, click properties, expand Metadata, and ensure that the content-type field is set correctly (use the working index page as a reference). Other than that I would say its possible the s3 website configuration is not correct so its serving them as files rather than a webpage.

Comment: @Mike Thanks that was indeed the case, the other files were uploaded by from my server in code rather than using the Amazon WebServer and had content set to application/octet-stream. For some reason text/html isnt listed in the drop down when I go to change it but entering it manually and the link now works.

Comment: @Mike how did you mange to get such a short stackoverflow name youve only been a member for a few months !

Comment: Great news - I'll post it as an answer if you wouldn't mind marking it as the answer for me? Cheers

Comment: of course not a problem

Comment: I've always wondered about that, I don't think there was any uniqueness check - i'm sure there must be other Mike's around

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its possible the content type has been messed up some how, click on the file in the s3 console page, click properties, expand Metadata, and ensure that the content-type field is set correctly (use the working index page as a reference).

Comment: Thanks that was indeed the case, the other files were uploaded by from my server in code rather than using the Amazon WebServer and had content set to application/octet-stream. For some reason text/html isnt listed in the drop down when I go to change it but entering it manually and the link now works.